# VBA - exporting Listbox header to worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Problem:  Objective is to export the data from ListBox1 and then separately export the headers.  Data export OK, no problem.  Header throws a runtime error 13, type mismatch.  Do you guys know why?  How can I fix this?

```
Private Sub ButtonSearchExport_Click()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook   '<<<< After export data, return to this original wb.
    With Workbooks.Add
        .Sheets(1).Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(Me.ListBox1.ListCount, Me.ListBox1.ColumnCount)) = Me.ListBox1.List

 ''''''''<<<< The error is from the line here:
        .Sheets(1).Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(Me.ListBox1.List(0), Me.ListBox1.ColumnCount)) = Me.ListBox1.List(0)

        Sheets(1).Name = "Transfer"
    End With
    wb.Activate
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `Me.ListBox1.List(0)` as the row parameter in the second reference to `Cells`, but `List(0)` is (probably?) not a number.  So this is an improvement:

```
.Sheets(1).Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, Me.ListBox1.ColumnCount)) = Me.ListBox1.List(0)
```

But now you've got a range of cells (1D array), and `List(0)` will just return the single item in the first row *and first column* of the list.  So that won't work either.

Unfortunately there is no way of extracting a single row or column from the `List` property as a 1D array.  You can either get a single cell using `.List(row, column)` or you can get the whole array using `.List`.  It gets worse: there's no way of directly setting or getting the column headers of a `ListBox` using VBA at all.  They always come from the row of cells just above the range specified in the `RowSource` property of the `ListBox`.

Fortunately for you, that gives you an easy (if rather roundabout) way to access the column headers - just look at the worksheet cells that are the source for the `ListBox` data:

```
Range(ListBox1.RowSource).Offset(-1, 0).Copy .Sheets(1).Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, Me.ListBox1.ColumnCount))
```

Note that this won't work if `RowSource` starts at the top of a sheet - if that's a possibility you'll need to test for it (I believe in that case the ListBox actually displays the Excel column headings - "Column A", "Column B" etc - as listbox headers!)

Comment: Aucuparia - thank you very much!!  Very enlightening comments.  I implemented, it works!